# Trying to add 3 days in Milliseconds to current Date

Tags: javascript, date

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var val = dateObj.getTime();
//86400 * 1000 * 3  Each day is 86400 seconds
var  days = 259200000;

val = val + days;
dateObj.setMilliseconds(val);
val = dateObj.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dateObj.getDate() + "/" + dateObj.getFullYear();
alert(val);
```

I am trying to take the current date, add three days of milliseconds to it, and have the date stamp show 3 days later from the current. For example - if today is 10/09/2012 then I would like it to say 10/12/2012.

this method is not working, I am getting the months and days way off. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you want setTime rather than setMilliseconds

Comment: Try: `dateObj.setTime(dateObj.getTime() + 8.64e7*3)` but note  daylight saving change overs may give unexpected results. Simpler to just add 3 to the date: `dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 3)`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To add time, get the current date then add, as milliseconds, the specific amount of time, then create a new date with the value:

```
// get the current date & time (as milliseconds since Epoch)
const currentTimeAsMs = Date.now();

// Add 3 days to the current date & time
//   I'd suggest using the calculated static value instead of doing inline math
//   I did it this way to simply show where the number came from
const adjustedTimeAsMs = currentTimeAsMs + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3);

// create a new Date object, using the adjusted time
const adjustedDateObj = new Date(adjustedTimeAsMs);
```

To explain this further; the reason `dataObj.setMilliseconds()` doesn't work is because it sets the dateobj's milliseconds PROPERTY to the specified value(a value between 0 and 999). It does not set, as milliseconds, the date of the object.

```
// assume this returns a date where milliseconds is 0
dateObj = new Date();

dateObj.setMilliseconds(5);
console.log(dateObj.getMilliseconds()); // 5

// due to the set value being over 999, the engine assumes 0
dateObj.setMilliseconds(5000);
console.log(dateObj.getMilliseconds()); // 0
```

References:
[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)
[`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
[`Date.setMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds)

Comment: I just var  days = 259200000 since it is static and never changes. Thanks! Curious, why didn't setMilliseconds(days) do the same?

Comment: I don't really know. I just know from experiance if it's static values, then do the calculations out like above.

Comment: Since this is (a year later) the first item to come up for adding milliseconds to a date, the reason setMilliseconds does not work is it sets the milliseconds portion of the date object.  So, in normal operation, it expects a number from 0-999.  However, it allows any number, and is like adding the value to the date without the previous milliseconds component of the date.

Comment: This example is really confusing because you use `var dateObj` to first store a number of milliseconds (from `Date.now()`) and then later store a Date object in it using `dateObj = new Date(dateObj);`.  It would be clearer for those who don't know how `Date.now()` works to use a separate variable, or perhaps stick with Date objects the whole time and use `Date.getTime()` for the addition of milliseconds.

Comment: @pseudocoder I've edited the example to use differing variables.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  This is straightforward to understand. It can be nested all together in one line `const threeDaysAway = new Date(Date.now() + 86400000 * 3);`

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```js
var dateObj = new Date(Date.now() + 86400000 * 3);
```

Dates in JavaScript are accurate to the millisecond, so `1000` is 1 second.
There are 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, and 24 hours in a day.

Therefore, one day is: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`, which is `86400000` milliseconds.

`Date.now()` returns the current timestamp, accurate to the millisecond.
We pass that timestamp, with the added 3 days worth of milliseconds to `new Date()`, which, when called with a number, creates a `Date` object from the provided timestamp.

Comment: It would be clearer to express the milliseconds as `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3` imo

Answer (score 10):

If you need to make date computations in javascript, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();
```

Comment: No offense on to you, but suggesting the use of an entire library to preform such a simple task seems quite over doing it.

Comment: There is nothing "simple" about this task. Consider daylight savings time changes.

Comment: Further reading: [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Answer (score 7):

Use this code

```
var dateObj = new Date(); 
var val = dateObj.getTime(); 
//86400 * 1000 * 3  Each day is 86400 seconds 
var  days = 259200000; 

val = val + days; 
dateObj = new Date(val); // ********important*********//
val = dateObj.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dateObj.getDate() + "/" + dateObj.getFullYear(); 
alert(val);
```

Comment: This answer does not take into account daylight savings.   If you specify an  initial date: var dateObject = new Date('Nov 2 2019'), adding 3 days you get 11/4/2019 inclusive which crosses over DST.  But if you start with var dateObj = new Date('Nov 4 2019'); you get 11/7/2019 which is 4 days inclusive.  Any ideas how to account for DST?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this for a more arbitrary `Date` object (other than `.now()`), you can use something like:

```js
const initialDate = new Date("March 20, 2021 19:00");

const millisecondsToAdd = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //30 days in milliseconds

const expiryDate = new Date(initialDate.valueOf() + millisecondsToAdd);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use external libraries or milliseconds, you simply add 3 to the current date.

```js
const threeDaysAfterToday = new Date();
threeDaysAfterToday.setDate(threeDaysAfterToday.getDate() + 3);
```